Google OAuth 2.0 Consent Screen Issue: Incorrect Consent Screen Displayed for Different Redirect URIs
I have two OAuth consent screens set up in the Google Developer Console. Both created form say first@gmail.com and second@gmail.com.
Javascript origin for first website is say first.com and for second website is say second.com. But the redirect URI for both websites are served from api.first.com. But again the endpoints are different here.
Example:
Redirect URI for first.com : http://api.first.com/api/google-auth/callback
Redirect URI for first.com : http://localhost:8080/api/google-auth/callback
Redirect URI for second.com : http://api.first.com/api/second/google-auth/callback
Redirect URI for second.com : http://localhost:8080/api/second/google-auth/callback
CLIENT_IDs for the two websites are also coming from two different gmail accounts hence are also different for both app.
For first.com, the oAuth flow is working fine both on localhost as well as after deployment.
BUT When both backend and frontend are running on LOCALHOST it is working as Expected.
NOTE: Both application are running on azure static web app.

Why is the consent screen from first.com being shown for both configurations even though the redirect URIs and CLIENT_ID are different for both first.com and second.com?


How can I ensure that the correct consent screen appears for each CLIENT_ID and redirect URI combination?

Please help me with this problem of utilizing google oAuth for my websites.

Let me clear a few things up.
The project on Google cloud console that you create has a consent screen.
It can also have one or more Clients.

Each application should have its own project.  If you have a development and production environment it should actually have two.
When you run your application you would use the client id from which ever project it is that you are running.  This is what will show the consent screen.
Who logs in has no effect on what consent screen is shown as it is the client id and client secret that point to a project.
